# Array in array with foreach

Tags: php, arrays

I have a new PHP problem. I have 2 arrays, and I want a third array which is a combination of the first 2. The first array, $arr1, is something like this:

```
Array (
    [0] => name [1] => age
)
```

The second array, $arr2, is something like this:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array( [0] => Dave [1] => 20 )
    [1] => Array( [0] => Steve [1] => 25 )
    [2] => Array( [0] => Ace [1] => 23 ) 
)
```

And my idea is to create a new array, called $arr3, which should like this:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array( [name] => Dave [age] => 20 )
    [1] => Array( [name] => Steve [age] => 25 )
    [2] => Array( [name] => Ace [age] => 23 ) 
)
```

Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$arr3 = array();
foreach ($arr2 as $person) {
    $arr3[] = array_combine($arr1, $person);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($arr2 as $subArray){
      foreach($subArray as $i=>$val){
             $arr3[$arr1[$i]] = $val;
      }
}
```